# What does the German part in "Feuerroter Pfeil und Bogen"/Guren No Yumiya mean?

Tags: attack-on-titan

1. The YouTube video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OkpRK2_gVs says it's "Sind Sie das Essen? Nein, wir sind die Jäger!"
2. However, the YouTube video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgBUP8TJqV8 writes "Sie sind das Essen und wir sind die Jäger!"

Depending on which translation it used, two different meanings can come across. In the first one, it's a rhetorical question "Are you the prey?" to what is responded to with "No, we are the hunters." In the second version, it appears to be more of an insult "You are the prey and we are the hunters."

Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

Both of the video's seem to get the first part of the lyrics wrong. However, the narrative on the first one, eg. question > answer, is indeed the one they tried to get across.

According to the CD booklet, the song 紅蓮の弓矢 歌詞 by Linked Horizon starts with the following sentences:

[image: Image from booklet]

- Image taken from taken from the full image at [Rafaelferrer.info](http://rafaelferrer.info/music/Shingeki%20no%20Kyojin%20Music%20Collection%20%5BMP3%5D/%5BNipponsei%5D%20Shingeki%20no%20Kyojin%20OP%20Single%20-%20Jiyuu%20he%20no%20Shingeki%20%5BLinked%20Horizon%5D/Scans/Booklet%2002.jpg)

All though a tad hard to read, the sentences seem to be as follows

> Seid ihr das Essen?
> Nein, wir sind der Jäger!

Leaving the correctness of the German pronunciation/usage aside, which is nicely covered on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ShingekiNoKyojin/comments/1mvoca/german_101_introsongtextdiscussion_sie_sind_das/), this would roughly translate to:

> Are you the food?
> No, we are the hunters!

Comment: Interestingly, [the AoT Wikia](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Feuerroter_Pfeil_und_Bogen#Trivia) mentioned this in the trivia section: "*The German line at the beginning of the song is often misheard as "Sie sind das Essen und wir sind die Jäger!" or something similar. According to the official lyrics provided in the booklet of the CD, the correct line is "Seid ihr das Essen? Nein, wir sind der Jäger!".*"